# Flutter custom emoji picker

Tags: flutter, keyboard, emoji

At the moment i try to create a custom textfield.
The textfield should open the emoji overview if i click on left icon.
Linke this:

[image]

I also look at the internet for a solution but i just found solutions with emoji picker.
I would only use libarys or packges from flutter (for more security).
Anyone have a idea how i can open directly the emoji keyboard?
Is there a way to do this?

Many thx (:

Answer (score 0):

You can use the package emoji_picker_flutter it is a custom emoji picker when selected only opens the emoji selector.